# Python polynomial integration function output error

Tags: math, python-3.x

```
def poly_integrate(terms,left_limit,right_limit):
    split_terms = terms.split('+')
    integral_fxdx = 'Integral:'
    integral = 0
    for term in split_terms:
        if (left_limit and right_limit) is None:
            #power term
            if 'x^' in term:
                split_term = term.split('x^')
                if float(split_term[1]) != -1:
                    int_coef = float(split_term[0])/(float(split_term[1])+1)
                    int_term = str(int_coef) + 'x^' + str(float(split_term[1]) + 1)
                    integral_fxdx = integral_fxdx + int_term
            if float(split_term[1]) == -1:
                int_term = split_term[0] + 'ln(x)'
                integral_fxdx = integral_fxdx + int_term
            #linear term
            if 'x' in term and ('^' not in term):
                split_term = term.split('x')
                int_term = str(float(split_term[0])/2) + 'x^2'
                integral_fxdx = integral_fxdx + int_term
            #constant
            if 'x' not in term:
                int_term = term + 'x'
                integral_fxdx = integral_fxdx + int_term
            #add plus or constant
            if term != terms[-0]:
                integral_fxdx = integral_fxdx + '+ '
            if term == terms[-0]:
                integral_fxdx = integral_fxdx + '+ C'
        return integral_fxdx
```

OUTPUT:

> > > Integral:0.25x^4.0+ 1.0x^3.0+ 1.0x^2+ 1x+ C3ln(x)+

So basically everything works except for when I integrate a x^-1 term. What is wrong so that the if clauses so that my function thinks the constant term is the last term and therefore returns the "C" early  and puts the ln(x) after? And why is the plus sign after the ln(x) as well? Been playing with this for a couple hours and can't figure it out...

When I do not include the x^-1 term everything works. If you wonder why I included left and right limits for an indefinite integral, I plan on making functionality to do either indefinite or definite integration within the funciton.

Comment: The indentation in your posted code looks off for several of the if statements.  You may want to double check that it matches the code you are running.  Example: the 'constant' check is nested inside of the 'linear' check in this code.  The 'constant' check "'x' not in term" will never evaluate to True, it is inside of a block that will only execute when "'x' in term" is True!

Comment: Instead of trying to find bugs in this code, my advice is to rewrite to work in two passes: first pass, parse the input into a structure which represents terms, coefficients, and exponents; second pass, compute the integral term by term, making use of the parse structure. If you have the parsed formula, it is easy to compute the integral, right? Maybe work on that first, get it out of the way. Then you are left with the more mechanical problem of parsing. It is a classic separation of concerns or divide and conquer approach.

Comment: This is an easy problem to solve if you use an IDE with a debugger.  A pass or two through the code will show you where your assumptions have gone awry.  The best IDEs on the market come from JetBrains; try PyCharm.

Comment: Yeah I just changed the constant check to match the code. It wasn't nestled in the initial loop and that works fine. I'll look at it in a debugger... I guess I'll rewrite the code to do two separate passes so that when I include the part with limits it can calculate without parsing again. Thanks